# Use Grunt object with load-grunt-tasks set-up

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using load-grunt-tasks with the associated tasks/options file structure which is working well. However I've encountered a small issue.

I'm looking to parse a JSON file and make the data in the resulting object available to one of my tasks: /tasks/options/concat.js to be precise.

I would like to use **grunt.file.readJSON** to parse the file - so the Grunt configuration doesn't have to be touched - however the grunt object isn't available in any of the /options/ 'partials': though it is of course in the main task files that reside in /tasks/.

So, ideally I'd like...

```
var concatData = grunt.file.readJSON('js/concat.json);
module.exports = {
    styles: {
        src: ['css/site.css'],
        dest: 'build/css/production.css'
},
    scripts: {
        files: [
            {src: concatData.head, dest: 'build/js/production-head.js'},
            {src: concatData.foot, dest: 'build/js/production-foot.js'}
        ]

    }
};
```

...but for the time being I've gone with this as a workaround...

```
var concatData = {
    "head" : [
        'js/modernizr-custom.js',
        'js/head.js'
    ],
    "foot": [
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'js/foot.js'
    ]
};
module.exports = {
    styles: {
        src: ['css/site.css'],
        dest: 'build/css/production.css'
    },
    scripts: {
        files: [
            {src: concatData.head, dest: 'build/js/production-head.js'},
            {src: concatData.foot, dest: 'build/js/production-foot.js'}
        ]
    }
};
```

Just for reference, the 'parent' task file is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'concurrent:phase1',
        'modernizr',
        'jshint',
        'concat',
        'concurrent:phase2',
        'clean',
        'notify:project',
        'watch'
    ]);
};
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Haven't you considered using usemin? https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

Comment: It'll be part of a Wordpress set-up, so not sure usemin is going to be that useful. Which is a shame!

Comment: maybe after a `var grunt = require('grunt');`?

Comment: That did the trick. Such a simple solution, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks Lajos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was, as Lajos suggested just a simple case of adding

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
```